# How to enable Cloud Billing export using the GCP console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm following the instructions at:

[Set up Cloud Billing data export to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-setup)

Steps 1-4 proceeded smoothly.

Step 5 is *Enable Cloud Billing export to the BigQuery dataset*.

Step 5.3 is *In the Billing navigation menu, select Billing export.*

Alas, I can spot no such item. All I see are:

- Overview
- Reports
- Account Management

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I must not have enough privileges. I happened to look at another project, one I created, and there are many more menu items, including *Billing Export*.

Comment: Can you check the differences in permissions in your current project and the one you created where you can Billing Export?
Which account are you using for this and what role does it have?

Comment: What permissions were you missing and that enable the menu?